# Generating image from PHP variable which contains HTML code when run through cron

Tags: php, html, cron, screenshot

I've PHP variable which contains some HTML code. For the sake of presentation, let's say the variable contains

```
// abc.php file
$table =  '<table>';
$table .=    '<tr><td>Hi there!</td></tr>';
$table .=    '<tr><td>How are you</td></tr>';
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

I'm planning to run `abc.php` through a cron job. So is it possible that the output that is to be generated by `abc.php` be converted into an image and get stored in a folder?

So basically when `abc.php` is done parsing, an image should be created when the cron job finishes. Is this even possible?

PS : I've looked at `Phantomjs` which seems ideally designed for such a task, but there are a few problems with it:

(a) It's platform dependent (Windows, Linux, Mac OS etc)

(b) I want to avoid using a `.exe` file on my server.

Comment: At least, you have to have "headless" web-browser to render content. Another option is to draw the table manually using `gd`.

Comment: Which is what `Phantomjs` does, right?

Comment: There are at least 2 similar topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963900/php-library-for-converting-html-to-image , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039627/convert-html-to-image-in-php-without-shell

Comment: Does it have to be saved as an image? Can't you just save the output as a static html file?

Comment: @jszobody It has to be saved as an image as it will used in a ppt file later.

Comment: @asprin I think you can use `wkhtmltoimage` on the file

Answer (score 0):

If you need only tables, it will be easier to you save the output as .xls file, which you'll can include to ppt file when you'll need it.