# Converting a DIV from html to an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I looked around for an app that could make a wallpaper out of my music library album art but I did not found one that could do even remotely what I wanted. So, instead, I built one in PHP. This script scans a folder for all the mp3 inside it then creates a tile wall out of the scrambled album covers. The output looks like [this](http://puu.sh/5J0xc.jpg). It is made out of a wrapper `div` with a `div` for every album art inside it as a background.
The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to convert all these images into one single image.
Is there any way I can convert this `div` into a single image, or maybe convert this `div` to a `canvas` and then save it as an image?

Attached image [image]

Comment: What about taking a picture of an html page that you make via a headless webkit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039627/convert-html-to-image-in-php-without-shell

Comment: Similar question [about creating a screenshot here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should forget your div, create an empty image with GD and add all your album covers one boy one : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Some kind of Example would be nice, if you know something ;)

Comment: I never did that before but I would try to create an empty image with the dimensions of your wallpaper : [imagecreate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php)

I would load all your covers in a loop (use an array with their path). [imagrecreatefromjpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)

For each cover, you can draw a cover inside the wallpaer. x will be equal to previous x + cover width, y will be equal to previous y + cover height (at the end of the line). [imagecopymerge](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)