# Save image from webpage using php

Tags: php, curl

I know my question is quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175392/how-to-save-webpage-as-a-image-file-using-php) and I'm using the answer to the problem as my solution but I can't get it to work.

I'm using [Immediatenet.com](http://immediatenet.com/) to generate a thumbnail of any given URL (example: [google](http://immediatenet.com/t/m?Size=1024x768&URL=http://google.com)).  And then using cURL to save the image in a folder on my server.

I'm not sure if the problem lies in the fact that the URL isn't actually an image URL (ie example.com/image.jpg) or a .html/.php URL or that I'm simply not doing it right. I've never used cURL before so it's distinctly possible that I'm not doing it right.

I'm saving the path to the image into a MySQL database which works just fine. However, the image doesn't actually save in the folder specified. The permissions are set correctly on the folder, so I don't think it's a permissions problem. I also set `allow_url_fopen` to On just to make sure.

My code is below. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this one?

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$url_new = 'http://immediatenet.com/t/m?Size=1024x768&URL='.$url;
$img = "/users/images/".$url.".jpg";
$ch = curl_init($url_new);
$fp = fopen($img, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: What's the value of `$url`? If it contains `/` characters, `$img` will be a path into a subdirectory, and you need to ensure that those subdirectories exist. Check for errors from `fopen()`.

Comment: E.g. if `$url` is `http://google.com`, you need to have a directory `/users/images/http:`.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm such an idiot. I just realised that you're totally correct. Those forward slashes are messing it up. Thank you. You should put this as the answer and I'll accept... begrudgingly because I feel like an idiot now. And hopefully get this question closed. Thank you so much. You've saved me hours of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$url` contains forward slashes (as most URLs do), these will be treated as directory delimiters in the `$img` pathname. You either need to replace the slashes with some other character, or create all the necessary directories.

```
$img = "/users/images/".str_replace('/', '_', $url).".jpg";
```

Comment: Thanks again, and for future reference if anyone is having the same problem. I also had a problem whereby it wouldn't save using "/users/...". I had to change it to "./users/...".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$img = "/users/images/".$url.".jpg";` is valid? .. do you really have a users folder in your root?

Please correct that if not and it should be ok.

Comment: There's a users folder for sure. I've saved images into that images folder before (for avatar uploads) but this one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By root I mean filesystem root (you are on unix-type) not your webroot.