# php print and save a div as .jpeg

Tags: php, jquery, image-generation, dynamic-image-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save webpage as a image file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175392/how-to-save-webpage-as-a-image-file-using-php)

i want user to enter few inputs then when he is done click save

all his inputs are sent to a php file that save these inputs and responde with

a new printable page that have a background image,and all inputs are shown on list positioned by css.
[image]

my question is is it possible to ..

1. trigger auto print after page showup
2. save this entier page as single jpeg on  server

my small project is using:php-html5-jquery-codeigniter 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a JPG of the page server-side using the GDI+ but it would require you placing text, etc, not relying on CSS, and a browser for layout... Failing that, you'd be better off generating a PDF which is designed for this.

As to printing, you can trigger the print dialogue using the following Javascript

```
windows.print()
```

Comment: And if user will be using WebKit printing dialog will show up where he can save it to PDF with no problem.

Comment: There are a number of ways to Print to Pdf on the client - WebKit browsers, PDF Writers for msot OSes, etc... The problem is, you can't just assume, you need to cater for the lowest possible denominator - which means server-side generation

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Call `window.print()` on load.
2. Yes, but that would be more difficult. You would need to generate your output as an image. PDF would probably be an easier option.

Answer (score 1):

To auto open the print dialogue:

```
function printpage() {
    window.print();
}
```

Or just straight out call `window.print();`

Answer (score 1):

You can either muck about with PDF generation, or you can set up [print-friendly CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).