# PHP Using imagegrabscreen

Tags: php, image, thumbnails, image-generation, dynamic-image-generation

How could I use imagegrabscreen to get a thumbnail image and a full size image of a specific website.

I was thinking that I could have an `array` that I feed the wanted uri's into but I am a bit stuck on how I would set the wxh of the image I need to grab.  I also think that I would need a `thumbnail class` and a `fullimage class` and call them when required.

Any better Ideas?

Comment: You would have to open a browser, navigate it to the url, THEN use `imagegrabscreen()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that imagaegrabscreen is Windows-only. If you have multiple displays set up, this function will only grab the primary display. Also, for this to work, your Apache service must be set to `Allow service to interact with desktop` otherwise you will just get a blank image.

This discussion covers the use of `imagegrabscreen` pretty well: [Getting imagegrabscreen to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631449/getting-imagegrabscreen-to-work)

There are a lot of other discussions about saving webpages as images, too - here are a few:

- [Website screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675)
- [Web Page Screenshots with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686858)
- [How can I generate a screenshot of a webpage using a server-side script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938)
- [PHP: How to capture browser window screen with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952570)
- [What is the best way to create a web page thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078)
- [Screenshot of current page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834445)
- [shell tool which renders web site including javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022338)
- [In any languages, Can I capture a webpage and save it image file? (no install, no activeX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077970)