# How I can print screen the whole information in one page without scrolling in any OS using PHP script?

Tags: php

Before this I used to implement print screen using these codes:

```
$question_id = 30;
$img = imagegrabscreen();
$image_name = random(10, 4).'_'.date('Ymmdd',time()).'_'.$question_id.'.png';             
imagepng($img, 'assets/images/report_abuse/'.$image_name);
```

I found that **imagegrabscreen()** only can be use in windows. How I can use **php script** to grab all one page information in any OS and not limited on specific webpage height but the along the page without scroll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9949268/3615630

Comment: How about without scroll? - I tried to avoid to use any api(s) since to avoid any issues on the future. @MohammadAlabed